# Gloval var scope

Tags: php

```
//index.php

    <?php
    include 'functions.php';
    head();
    ?>


//functions.php
    global $a;
    $a="text";
    function head(){   
    echo $a;
    }
```

Doing this will not print me the value of $a. Why?

Comment: Because `$a` is local variable in the scope of function `head()` unless declared otherwise. And it wasn't declared otherwise.

Comment: please read: http://nz1.php.net/language.variables.scope.php it will answer your question in less time than it took to post your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `$a` in function `head` is local variable for this function. You have to explicitly declare that you want to use global

```
<?php
global $a;
$a="text";
function head(){   
    global $a;
    echo $a;
}
```